# Nested for-loops with numbers going down columns

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

So, obvious newbie here... My goal is to output a table with eight columns and ten rows with the numbers 1 through 80. This must be done using **nested for loops** (for an assignment). This is what I have so far:

```
int num = 1; //start table of numbers at one

for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) //creates 10 rows
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) //creates 8 columns
    {
        cout << num << "\t" ; //print each number
        num = num + 10;
    }

    cout << num;
    num++;

    cout << endl; //output new line at the end of each row
}
```

But my output should look like this:

```
1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71
2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72
...
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
```

Am I even in the right direction? How do I do this? Right now, only the first row is correct when I print it.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugger. Even better, pencil-and-paper debug your program - pretend you are a computer and execute your programm line-by-line, using a pen and a paper to write down values of every variable you encounter. You will quickly see the error.

Comment: This is really about logic rather than programming. Just think about i) what order your numbers are being printed in, and ii) what happens to num each time. To answer your question, the structure of your code is OK.

Comment: *Am I even in the right direction?* -- What is wrong with the other lines?  If you can answer that question, then you should be able to figure out on your own what to do.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
int num = 1; //start table of numbers at one

for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) //creates 10 rows
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) //creates 8 columns
    {
         cout << num << "\t" ; //print each number
         num += 10;
    }
num = row + 2;
cout << endl; //output new line at the end of each row
}
```

EDIT: FIXED

Comment: No, the output won't match OP's assignment.

Comment: Ohh, yes just noticed. I will change it

Comment: Done, sorry for before

Comment: Why are you depriving OP of the chance to figure the problem and learn from mistakes?

Comment: Just trying to help. Obviously, he already tried. Sorry, if you see it that way.

Comment: Thank you, @DimChtz. I have been trying to figure out for hours. Can you tell me what the "num = row + 2" part does, though?

Comment: @littmuslozenge Well, it's like the "step" of the rows. I don't know how to explain it better. Try to give it different values and you will understand

Answer (score 0):

We beginners should help each other. Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLS = 8;

    for ( int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++ )
    {
        for ( int col = 0; col < COLS; col++ )
        {  
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << row + 1 + ROWS * col << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
 1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 
 2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 
 3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 
 4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 
 5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 
 6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 
 7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 
 8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 
 9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
```

You are in the right direction except the variable `num` is being changed incorrectly.:) For example after the first iteration of the outer loop `num` is equal to (if I am not mistaken) `72`.

Here is a more general approach that allows to set the initial value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLS = 9;
    const int INITIAL_VALUE = 10;

    for ( int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++ )
    {
        for ( int col = 0; col < COLS; col++ )
        {  
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << INITIAL_VALUE + row + ROWS * col << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 
12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 
13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93 
14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94 
15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95 
16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96 
17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97 
18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98 
19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99
```

Comment: Not the down voter but helping out should not be here is the code that does your assignment.  It should guide the user to what the flaw in the logic is.

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not bother about down-votings. :) I simply ignore them.:)